# Notepad++ plugin SnippetPlus - exporting snippets?

Tags: export, notepad++, code-snippets

Is it possible to export snippets with this plugin and then import into other PC's notepad++?

Where does SnippetPlus store all snippets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're in `plugins/Config/SnippetPlus.xml`. Copying this file over should be enough

Comment: Complete path: C:\Users\triven\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\plugins\config